# Access Reading Thorugh UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically what I'm trying to do today is that in case of Access database file being corrupt, I have a VB function that exports all form elements into text files, using the following Transfer/SaveAs commands:

```
accApp.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, destFile, True, , 65001

accApp.SaveAsText acForm, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Form_" & d.Name & ".txt"
```

This function is set to run dynamically, so that based on given source database file path, it performs the task. For the most part the Access objects do successfully export as text file, but for Access objects that are named with special characters (e.g. "Client Info/Status", "Client Report: Based on Region"), the code ignores these objects. Removing the error handling lines returns the infamous 3011 error. Is there a way to force Access to have strings with UTF-8 characters into valid paths as vba is running? By adding in a Reference perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Characters like `/` or `:` are illegal in file names in Windows, so you can't use these names for your files. You'll have to replace these characters.

Try naming a file `some/file.txt` and Explorer will tell you what isn't allowed.